# Kubernetes - HPA metrics - memory & cpu together

Tags: kubernetes

Is it possible to keep 'cpu' and 'memory' metrics together as shown below ? This seems to be not working. I tried below script as HPA. But instently pods has grown upto 5.
That's not what i was expecting.

```
apiVersion: autoscaling/v2beta1
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  name: myservice-metrics
  namespace: myschema
spec:
  scaleTargetRef:
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    name: myservice
  minReplicas: 1
  maxReplicas: 5
  metrics:
  - type: Resource
    resource:
      name: memory
      targetAverageValue: 500Mi
  - type: Resource
    resource:
      name: cpu
      targetAverageUtilization: 70
```

If i keep it individually, it is not complaining. Is it the best practice to set both the metrics for a service ? is there any other way to set both the metrics.

```
apiVersion: autoscaling/v2beta1
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  name: myservice-metrics-memory
  namespace: myschema
spec:
  scaleTargetRef:
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    name: myservice
  minReplicas: 1
  maxReplicas: 3
  metrics:
  - type: Resource
    resource:
      name: memory
      targetAverageValue: 500Mi


apiVersion: autoscaling/v2beta1
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  name: myservice-metrics-cpu
  namespace: myschema
spec:
  scaleTargetRef:
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    name: myservice
  minReplicas: 1
  maxReplicas: 3
  metrics:
  - type: Resource
    resource:
      name: cpu
      targetAverageUtilization: 70
```

Comment: what's the complaint?

Comment: can we keep both metrics in single yaml file ? If yes, is it the standard way to do it...

Comment: You said **If i keep it individually, it is not complaining**, so I though there is a complaint. You can have two metrics, yes, but it is not very common. Now, if it makes sense to you (your application wise), you definitely should put them both.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from Kubernetes v1.6 support for scaling based on multiple metrics has been added.
I would suggest to try and switch to the `autoscaling/v2beta2` API.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/#support-for-multiple-metrics

Answer (score 0):

https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubernetes-api/workload-resources/horizontal-pod-autoscaler-v2beta2/

`metrics` is of type `[]MetricSpec` and

> the maximum replica count across all metrics will be used

Single file is possible.